# What benefits there are by importing types vs using a declaration file in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Our team is transitioning from plain JS to TS. One thing that I've found super annoying is having to import types. They do nothing IMO but pollute the import space. I've found that defining my types in a declaration file allows me not to have to import the type. Most of my engineers argue that importing types is "better" than having a "global" declaration. I'm not convinced... Are there any benefits to importing types instead of defining them in a declarations file? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By importing types from files you can't get duplicates, this can be a huge plus if you have a large codebase where some type names may overlap.

But in the end of the day it boils down to personal opinion. Both will work but keep in mind that your global type file gets **bloated** very quickly.

other peoples' thoughts: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/g165mn/people_who_import_their_global_types_where_do_you/)

But good luck with your transitioning!